# How to make a table view in iOS Swift 2?

Tags: ios

Hey I'm new to xcode need help on this very topic! Thanks! Code example is most suitable.

Comment: Whoever up voted this question (and ones like it) need to review the reason to up vote a question. Hover your mouse over the up vote arrow. What does it say? "This question shows research effort, it is useful and clear". This question demonstrates none of those qualities. It clearly shows no effort.

Comment: I don't understand how these questions appear on SO. Typing the exact title in Google gives you plenty of results.

Comment: Google "swift table view tutorial" or similar keywords and you'll find many references.

Answer (score 0):

I think apple's documentation on ["Create a Table View"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson7.html) is the best place to look for this.